# Why can I deploy an app to Heroku and not Dropbox?

Tags: heroku, dropbox

I have a node app and I'm just curious what differentiates a hosting solution like Heroku from Dropbox. Why can I only deploy an app to Heroku and not Dropbox? Both are able to store data. Why is only one able to run my app?

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox doesn't execute code in your folders. Because of this, you can serve up static files from Dropbox, but not anything that requires running code server side.

Heroku recently announced beta support for Dropbox Sync, which lets you deploy the contents of Dropbox folders to Heroku apps: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/11/19/announcing_beta_dropbox_sync